# Unix- Copying the same file from multiple directories into a new directory while renaming the files

Tags: unix, loops, copying, renaming

I have 36 subdirectories in the same directory named 10,11,12,....45 and a subdirectory logs

in each subdirectory (except for the directory logs) there is the same file called log.lammps

i was wondering if there was a way where i could copy each log.lammps file from each subdirectory 10-45 and put it in the sub directory logs while also adding the number of the directory that it originated from to the end of the filename

so i am looking for a code that copies the file log.lammps one by one from each subdirectory and every time the file gets copied into the directory logs, the filename gets changed from log.lammps to log.lammps10 if it came from the subdirectory 10 and when the file log.laamps from subdirectory 11 is copied into logs its name changes to log.lammps11 etc.

any help would be appreciated since right now i am only dealing with 30-40 files and in time i will be working with hundreds of files

Comment: Would you care to accept one of the answers if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy-peasy with the magic of shell scripting.  I'm assuming you have bash available.  Create a new file in the directory that contains these subdirectories; name it something like `copy_logs.sh`.  Copy-paste the following text into it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# copy_logs.sh

# Copies all files named log.lammps from all subdirectories of this
# directory, except logs/, into subdirectory logs/, while appending the name
# of the originating directory.  For example, if this directory includes
# subdirectories 1/, 2/, foo/, and logs/, and each of those directories
# (except for logs/) contains a file named log.lammps, then after the
# execution of this script, the new file log.lammps.1, log.lammps.2, and
# log.lammps.foo will have been added to logs/.  NOTE: any existing files
# with those names in will be overwritten.

DIRNAMES=$( find . -type d | grep -v logs | sed 's/\.//g' | sed 's/\///g' | sort )

for dirname in $( echo $DIRNAMES )
do
    cp -f $dirname/foo.txt logs/foo$dirname
    echo "Copied file $dirname/foo.txt to logs/foo.$dirname"
done
```

See the script's comments for what it does.  After you've saved the file, you need to make it executable by commanding `chmod a+x copy_logs.sh` on the command line.  After this, you can execute it by typing `./copy_logs.sh` on the command line while your working directory is the directory that contains the script and the subdirectories. If you add that directory to your $PATH variable, you can command `copy_logs.sh` no matter what your working directory is.

(I tested the script with GNU bash v4.2.24, so it should work.)

For more on bash shell scripting, see any number of books or internet sites; you might start with the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: Looking at my code again, I noticed that all directory names that include the string `logs` will be dropped when variable `DIRNAMES` is assigned to. To fix this, the script could be adapted to search only for directories whose names consist of digits. However, instead of relying on the naming conventions of directories, what I would do is to move the "logs" subdirectory away from the directory in question, so that I can rely on all the subdirectories being of a certain type -- in this case, of the type that will contain a `log.lammps` file. It just makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line should work:

```
for f in [0-9][0-9]/log.lammps; do
  d=$(dirname ${f})
  b=$(basename ${f})
  cp ${f} logs/${b}.${d}
done
```